# I have issue with sizeof keyword in php code

Tags: php, mysql

i am having a database data which represent like this

Table name `books`

```
song  song1  book1  book2  book3 //column names
ACD   ----   ASD    der    ----  //row 1 i dont want sizeof to count ---- as 1 
dre   ----   huy    ----   Der   //row 2
```

I want to check the size of song and book so i used

```
$sql = 'Select  from books';
$result = mysql_query($sql);
while($row =  mysql_fetch_array($result))
{     
      $song = row['song'];
      $song1 = row['song1'];
      $book1 = row['book1'];
      $book2 = row['book2'];
      $book3 = row['book3'];

      $sw = sizeof($song);
      $sw1 = sizeof($song1);
      $b1 = sizeof($book1);
      $b2 = sizeof($book2);
      $b3 = sizeof($book3); //sizeof function is not working for me 
}
```

the above database has `----` right then it is `0` but the sizeof function is counting as `1` and showing `1` only i need `0` whereever there are `----`

i dont want sizeof to count `----` as `1` but as `0` in every database field even for `null` also it is working like this.......

how to code it and display

Comment: I do not quite follow what you are trying to do? Are you after a boolean to check if there is a value in the field?

Or are you trying to check if the value is not ----? I would also like to note I did not downvote this I just think it needs further explanation!

Comment: no no i just want the size of books and song but wherever there is ---- in database it will return as 1 but i need it as 0

Answer (score 0):

**sizeof() function is used to get number of elements in an array, and you are using in different context,** your database records i believe are not having array information.

Assuming you are looking for a TRUE(1) FLASE(0) scenario, here is a snippet that can help

```
  $sw = ( !empty($song) && $song!='----' )?TRUE:FALSE;
  $sw1 = ( !empty($song1) && $song1!='----' )?TRUE:FALSE;

  $b1 = ( !empty($book1) && $book1!='----' )?TRUE:FALSE;
  $b2 = ( !empty($book2) && $book2!='----' )?TRUE:FALSE;
  $b3 = ( !empty($book3) && $book3!='----' )?TRUE:FALSE;
```

Comment: i need a count of it like it must go 2 3 4 excluding ----

Comment: i dont want true or false

Comment: @sleepy do you mean you want number of records under a particular field name. Also explain how is 2, 3, 4 estimated with respect to a single record.